# In React.js, is there a way for providing particular props to all the sub-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

Thank you for viewing this question, and I also appreciate for thinking about this issue.

I'm looking for the way for providing particular props to whole the sub-components in React.js

I know that in such cases, we normally use context or a store package like recoil, and get the data from sub-components like below.

In this example, parent-component passes the `disabled` state to sub-components via context, and sub-components consume the provided data using `useContext`.

```
const DisableContext = createContext({});

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  return (
    <DisableContext.Provider value={{ disabled }}>
      <button onClick={() => setDisabled((old) => !old)}>{disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}</button>
      <ChildComponent />
    </DisableContext.Provider>
  )
}

const ChildComponent = () => {
  const { disabled } = useContext(DisableContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>ChildComponent</p>
      <span>Parent is {disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}</span>
      <GrandChildComponent />
    </div>
  )
}

const GrandChildComponent = () => {
  const { disabled } = useContext(DisableContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>GrandChildComponent</p>
      <span>Parent is {disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But in my case in this time, I want to pass the data to whole the sub-components as `props` . And I don't want to code the consuming code(`useContext` in this case) in each sub-components.

I know that `cloneElement` can override original props of child component and can use it for passing the props without coding consuming code in the child component, like below.

However, with the example below, the grand child component can't listen to the change of grand-parent component's props. Only the direct child component can listen to the `disabled` via props.

Or, we can apply `cloneElement` recursively for passing the props to whole sub-component. But I know that it can be heavy process and I'd like to avoid that pattern.

Is there any good way for achieving my requirement?

```
const WrapperComponentWhichPassesDisabledAsProps = ({ children, disabled }) => {
  return cloneElement(children, { disabled })
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setDisabled((old) => !old)}>{disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}</button>
      <WrapperComponentWhichPassesDisabledAsProps disabled={disabled}>
        <ChildComponent />
      </WrapperComponentWhichPassesDisabledAsProps>
    </>
  )
}

const ChildComponent = ({ disabled }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>ChildComponent</p>
      <span>Parent is {disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}</span>
      <SomeComponentWhichTakesNoProps />
    </div>
  )
}

// This component doesn't get `disabled` props from upper component.
// So `GrandChildComponent` is isolated from `ChildComponent`
const SomeComponentWhichTakesNoProps = () => {
  return <GrandChildComponent />
}

const GrandChildComponent = ({ disabled }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>GrandChildComponent</p>
      <span>Parent is {disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[What I tried]

1. I tried it with `cloneElement` but I found that it can't fill my requirement.
2. I tried it by using recursive pattern. It can achieve my requirement, but the process can be very heavy

[What I expect]

1. Passing { disabled: boolean } props to whole the sub-components
2. I hope the sub-components to be simple react-components which apply the `disabled` as props without any special consuming code like `useContext` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Props can be passed down as many levels as you need. Something like this should do the trick:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setDisabled((old) => !old)}>{disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}</button>
    <ChildComponent disabled={disabled} />
  )
}

const ChildComponent = ({ disabled }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>ChildComponent</p>
      <span>Parent is {disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}</span>
      <GrandChildComponent disabled={disabled} />
    </div>
  )
}

const GrandChildComponent = ({ disabled }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>GrandChildComponent</p>
      <span>Parent is {disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer .
Unfortunately it's not I want. 
I'm thinking of the case the `GrandChildComponent` can't directly receive the props from direct upper component.
(I'm sorry. The example was confusing. Please see the updated one)